# Discrete convolution of generalized pentagonal number sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, convolution

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of integers defined as $$a_n= \left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
(-1)^k & \text{if }n=\frac{k(3k\pm 1)}{2}\\
1 & \text{if } n=0\\
0 & \text{else }
\end{array}
\right.$$

How can I find a closed form for the discrete convolution $b_n = a_n \ast a_n$ defined by:

$$b_l = \sum_{n=0}^{l} a_n a_{l-n}$$

? This may be a simple and elementary problem, but I am struggling on getting a solution. Any help will be welcomed.

Thank you.